# My car no longer recognizes media on my iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, music, ipod, car-integration

I recently switched to Spotify after using the Apple Music app. My car was able to recognize the song name and time, etc.

After I switched to Spotify and deleted Music, my car doesn't recognize anything anymore -- it just plays the music without any information. I am using a Lightning cable to connect my iPhone 7 (running iOS 12.0) to Mazda 6 2017.

### Before deleting Music app:

[image: Before deleting MUSIC App]

### After deleting Music app:

[image: After deleting MUSIC App]

**but my friend's iPhone is working with my car so the issue with My iPhone!**

Comment: what do you mean? everything was good before I delete "Apple Music" App!

Comment: it depends on the car been able to use/understand the Spotify meta data stream. Since Apple is more popular most cars can read it, not so for Spotify. So check with your Car manufacturer.

Comment: the car was able to understand Spotify metadata stream as I said before deleting the app, I can read the song name and control from my steering wheel (Spotify).

Comment: Are you sure it was after deleting Apple Music, as opposed to after updating to iOS 12? A lot of car systems need firmware updates to keep pace with iOS.

Comment: yes it was after deleting, because I was using Apple Music with iOS 12.0 without any issues

Comment: but my friend's iPhone is working with my car so the issue with My iPhone!

Comment: Does your friend's iPhone still have Apple Music installed?

Comment: Can you reinstall Apple Music and see whether it works then?

Comment: My friends using another app called "Anghami", and i reinstalled the apple music... not working either.

Comment: i tried with another 2 friends, the issue happens with mine only.

Comment: Can you please update your question with all the things you've clarified in the comments? You don't need to indicate the changes in the text itself (everybody interested can look at the edit history), just rewrite the whole question now that Apple Music doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Ah, please also add which version of iOS your friends are using.

Comment: And, now that I think of it, screenshots from the CarPlay settings in the phones (assuming there is such a thing, I don't have CarPlay here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it:

(You Must Have Apple Music with one song at least).

1. Power cycle your phone by powering off and powering on.
2. Open Apple Music and play any downloaded song.
3. Connect USB/lightning cable while the music still playing on the phone.

Now you can see the song name on the screen and controllable by steering wheel, and you can use any app that plays music it will be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. The iPhone volume/the music volume is not on 0
2. The lightning adapter is plugged in properly and working
3. When you play some music, at the bottom tap all devices:

[image: all devices]

Then select your car. If your car isn’t being recognised it is probably a problem with the cable/the ports.

Comment: not working, i've used more than 3 cables

Comment: @MhdGhamde Ok. Have you checked that the app is detecting the car as an input source?

Comment: i think Spotify or any app doesn't detecting my car as an input source because it's not a Display it's Normal Radio with USB Media

Comment: The audio is ok but no information on the radio screen